# I cannot reinstall Cinnamon on Ubuntu 12.04. How can I do so?

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon

I had installed Cinnamon 1.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 earlier but I couldn't upgrade it to 1.6+.
I uninstalled (and purged) it to do a fresh install; but now I am getting an error as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cinnamon
```

I tried installing the foo packages (needed for Cinnamon) but I get the same error:

```
sudo apt-get install foo1 foo2 foo3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package foo1
E: Unable to locate package foo2
E: Unable to locate package foo3
```

I tried updating the repositories using apt-get update but it is no use.

Comment: I never knew `foo` was a package. Have you tried `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi actually Cinnamon repository not existed in Ubuntu. You have to add its PPA if you want to install it.

So to install that open your terminal and paste these steps one by one .

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinnamon cinnamon-session cinnamon-settings
```

Comment: hey it worked thanx...

can you tell me how to install nemo and make it the default file manager...